# How to close certain activities after a certain screen?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, activity-finish

There are 4 main activities:

```
    ProfileMenu.class

    CreateNewProfileStepOne.class

    CreateNewProfileStepTwo.class

    MainMenu.class
```

Suppose from ProfileMenu.class, the user chooses "Create new profile" as an action. This launches CreateNewProfileStepOne.class, where the user enters data such as name, address, etc. The same goes on in CreateNewProfileStepTwo.class. At this point, the user may freely go back and forth between CreateNewProfileStepOne and CreateNewProfileStepTwo with all data being saved and passed via intents. If the user backs up from CreateNewProfileStepOne.class, all entered data is lost, and the user will have to enter from scratch again.

After hitting "Confirm Profile" button in the CreateNewProfileStepTwo.class activity, however, I want to send the user to MainMenu.class, as well as kill the previous activities ProfileMenu,CreateNewProfileStepOne and CreateNewProfileStepTwo.

**How would I kill those 3 activities right as I enter MainMenu.class? From what I know, finish() only acts upon one and only one activity--the current one it is called from. I don't want to kill A,B,or C until I'm ready to enter D. And when I enter D, I want to kill A,B,and C simultaneously.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are creating an `Intent` to launch `MainMenu` add this flag to the Intent : [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyCurrentActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

No history will be retained and the user won't be able to go back to the previous activities

Comment: Alright. Just out of curiosity though, what if I actually want to kill B and C, but leave A open for returning to if the hits back/up from D?

Comment: If you don't want to return a result to activity A, just launch it with `startActivity` or `startActivityForResult`. If you need to return a result, launch activities B and C with this flag :`FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS̀ , B and C won't be kept in history and you reult will return to activity A

Answer (score 2):

Activities are killed when you left them to go to another activity. Switching back and forth between these activities is done by recreating those activities.

Comment: I see. Say a user entered some data into an EditText box and moved onto another screen. When the user presses the System BACK button, that text will still be there. But when the user presses the action bar UP button, everything is reset. How do I recreate the memory that the BACK button has? Do I have to use intents?